# how to do browser setting to record the application which uses VPN

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to record telecom application example https://example.com using Jmeter which will work only with VPN.

And I am getting diffculties to do Global setting in Https Tes script recorder and in browser configuration.

I tried to record Web Tour application in my local machine with below setting and I was able to do it.

[HTTPs Test Script recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu6B0.png)

Comment: I was not able to post browser setting details above.

Comment: Address: localhost and port: 8080(In LAN settings)

Answer (score 0):

First of all machine running JMeter needs to be connected to the VPN. If JMeter won't be able to reach the application being recorded - all other steps won't make any sense.

Second: you need to put `*.example.com` into "HTTPS Domains" field of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) so:

1. Replace your `127.0.0.1` value with the `*.example.com`
2. Stop HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
3. Remove `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` from JMeter's "bin" folder
4. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
5. Install the new `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file into your browser

Recording should work now.

References:

- [Tests Recording since JMeter 2.10](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)